# Stuck on buttons and text input in html

Tags: html, button, input, logic

I'm currently working on a simple flag guessing game, where the user sees a flag and input's the country it is, but I'm finding it hard to take a value from the text input and put it into logic. My function for the button does run but doesn't make it to the if statements, seemingly not reading the text in the input.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>The America's</title>

</head>
<body>

<img src = "Colombia.png">
</br>
<p><em>The flag shown above is which countries flag?</em></p>
<h1 id="flag">...</h1>
<h2 id = "guess">...</h2>
<h3 id = "result">...</h3>

<input id="guessfun" type ="text">
<!-- 
<button id="enter">Enter</button> -->
<button id = "button_enter" onclick="guess()">Enter</button>

<script>

function guess(){
  alert("f")
  flag.textContent = guess.value;
   if (guessfun == "Colombia"){
     result.textContent = ("Yes! That's the flag of" + guess.value);
     alert("Yes")
  }
    else if (guessfun =! "Colombia") {
      result.textContent = ("No! That's the Colombian Flag!");
      alert("No")
 }
}


onclick = guess();  



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Declaring an `id` in the HTML does not automatically create a corresponding variable accessible through JavaScript, you must first retrieve this element thanks to its `id` with [`document.getElementById()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

In the example below I use it to retrieve the entered value, then I use it again to display the result:

```js
function guess(){
  var input = document.getElementById('guessfun').value
  var result = "No! That's the Colombian Flag!"  
   if (input == "Colombia"){
     result = (`Yes! That's the flag of ${input}`);
  }    
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result 
}
```

```html
<img height="36px" src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Flag_of_Colombia.svg/1280px-Flag_of_Colombia.svg.png">
<br>
<p><em>The flag above is the flag of which country?</em></p>
<h3 id = "result">...</h3>

<input id="guessfun" type ="text">
<button onclick="guess()">Enter</button>
```

Comment: Hi! I tried your solution, but before I press the button or input anything into the text box, the "No! That's the Colombian Flag" answer popped up, any reason why this would happen?

Comment: Because you probably call the function at start. Remove your `onclick = guess();` (in the `<script>` tags) if it is still there, like in your original question.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you!

However, I can't click the enter button/when I click it nothing happens, how would you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Not gonna lie, your code is pretty messed up. You should probably clean it up. You're trying to access variables that you've never defined(`flag`, `guess`). To access the elements, use document.getElementById(). I'm also not seeing what flag.textContent is for. You should instead directly access the input when checking.

```
function guess(){
   var guess = document.getElementById("guessfun").textContent;
   var result = document.getElementById("result");
   if (guess == "Colombia"){
     result.textContent = ("Yes! That's the flag of" + guess.value);
  }
    else if (guessfun =! "Colombia") {
      result.textContent = ("No! That's the Colombian Flag!");
 }
}
```

Additionally, you should probably remove the onclick from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

replace  `else if (guessfun =! "Colombia") {` by `else {`, No need Of putting `else if` there. Because if `guess == "Colombia"` dosent match then its always not equal to `"Colombia"`.

And You Haven't Defined `flag`, `result` and `guessfun`
You can define them like this

```
const flag = document.getElementById("flag");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const guessfun = document.getElementById("guessfun");
```

You Can Apply More Than One Flag, Try Below Snippet

*Snippet*

```js
var currFlag;
var currId;
const v = document.getElementById("guessfun");
const r = document.getElementById("result");
const flag = document.getElementById("flag");
setFlag();

function setFlag(pre = -1){
  flag.src = "";
  r.innerHTML = "...";
  v.value = "";
  document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = "...";
  var flags = [];
  flags.push(
    {"Name" : "Colombia", "Src":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Flag_of_Colombia.svg/255px-Flag_of_Colombia.svg.png"},
    {"Name" : "USA", "Src":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/220px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png"},
    {"Name" : "Sri Lanka", "Src":"https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flag-sri-lanka-lion-vector-260nw-195385355.jpg"},
    {"Name" : "UK", "Src":"https://cdn.britannica.com/25/4825-004-F1975B92/Flag-United-Kingdom.jpg"}
    );
  currId = getRandomId(flags.length, pre);
  currFlag = flags[currId];
  flag.src = currFlag.Src;

}
function guess(){
    document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = v.value;
    if(v.value.toLowerCase() == currFlag.Name.toLowerCase()){
      r.innerHTML = "Hooray! You Won. <a href='#' onclick='setFlag("+currId+")'>Click to Guess again<a>";
    }
    else{
      r.innerHTML = "The Correct Answer Is: "+currFlag.Name+". <a href='#' onclick='setFlag("+currId+")'>Click to try again<a>";
    }
}
function getRandomId(max, pre = -1) {
    var ret;    
    ret = Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
    if(ret > max || ret < 0 || ret == pre){ ret = getRandomId(max, pre) }
    return parseInt(ret);
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>The America's</title>

</head>
<body>

<img id="flag" width="50px" />
<p><em>The flag shown above is which countries flag?</em></p>
<h1 id="flag">...</h1>
<h2 id = "guess">...</h2>
<h3 id = "result">...</h3>

<input id="guessfun" type ="text">
<button id = "button_enter" onclick="guess()">Enter</button>

</body>
</html>
```